# Are there some free NHibernate generator tool with C#, NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes?

Tags: nhibernate, attributes, generator

Are there some free NHibernate generator tool with C#, NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes? 
I don't want to use the xml mapping file, but want to use attributes, do you know some good generator tools which can support the latest version of NHibernate 3.3.1? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer for the nmg codeplex tool. There was a new release this afternoon, if you still get an error, post the exception on codeplex and I will fix it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Hi, I can remember that there were always the exception "Object reference not set to an instance of object" before when click "Connect", but I am unable to reproduce it now may be caused by my framework 4 been upgraded recently I am not sure whether it is the reason. Now I can use it to generate code and looks like great, thank you!

A question, I am used to use the component of "NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes" to implement mappings, do the NMG also support using this component feature to generate NH code?

Comment: Thanks for sharing us a great and free tool, i'm just new guy in Nhibernate and just used it few hour ago, just one thing "Great tool" :), keep up the work

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate mapping generator.  This is probably the best free one I've found.

http://nmg.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use TT templates, mygeneration or and other tool which makes code based on templates. The tool is just a code generator, it does not know anything from NHibernate. The templetes you make will do the magic of generating for a specific product/version.

Comment: That would be complicated, is there any easier tool?